SideBar covering part of Header
In React js, I have a Header component and a SideBar (Mini variant drawer) component in different files, and only the SideBar drawer is from MUI 5 in dashboard page.
How can I make Header on top of the SideBar or shift the logo to the right in the header when the drawer is opened?
the solutions I found are when the header and sidebar are both from MUI, but I didn't use MUI in my header, just CSS.
---------
How it looks, when closed and opened:
enter image description here
How I wanted it to look:
enter image description here
---------
Header css:
.navbar {
  background-color: #e0edbf;
}
.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 16px 0;
  background-color: #e0edbf;
  margin: 0 5.5rem;
}
.nav-logo {
  width: 11rem;
}
.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.nav-menu li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

Header:
const Header = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"))

  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch()

  const { isLoggedIn, userData } = useUsersState()
  const { cartItems } = useCartState()

  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logoutUser())
  }

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-container">
        <div className="nav-logo">
          <Link to="/">
            <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
          </Link>
        </div>
        {isMatch ? (
          <>
            <div className="nav-xs-cart">
              <div className="nav-login-cart">
                {isLoggedIn && (
                  <>
                    {/* <ul>
                      <li>
                        <Link
                          className="nav__link"
                          to={`/dashboard/${
                            userData && userData.role == "admin" ? "admin" : "user"
                          }`}
                        >
                          {userData && userData.role == "admin" ? "Admin Dashboard" : "My Account"}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                    </ul> */}
                    <Link className="nav__link" to="/" onClick={handleLogout}>
                      <button>Logout</button>
                    </Link>
                  </>
                )}
                {!isLoggedIn && (
                  <>
                    <Link className="nav__link" to="/login">
                      <button>Login</button>
                    </Link>
                  </>
                )}

                <Link to="/cart">
                  <CartIcon value={cartItems && cartItems.length > 0 ? cartItems.length : 0} />
                </Link>
              </div>

              <DrawerNav />
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <ul className="nav-menu">
              <li>
                <Link className="nav__link" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link className="nav__link" to="/products">
                  Products
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link className="nav__link" to="/about">
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div className="nav-login-cart">
              {isLoggedIn && (
                <>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        className="nav__link"
                        to={`/dashboard/${userData && userData.role == "admin" ? "admin" : "user"}`}
                      >
                        {userData && userData.role == "admin" ? "Admin Dashboard" : "My Account"}
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <Link className="nav__link" to="/" onClick={handleLogout}>
                    <button>Logout</button>
                  </Link>
                </>
              )}
              {!isLoggedIn && (
                <>
                  <Link className="nav__link" to="/login">
                    <button>Login</button>
                  </Link>
                </>
              )}

              <Link to="/cart" className="nav-login-cart__cart">
                <CartIcon value={cartItems && cartItems.length > 0 ? cartItems.length : 0} />
              </Link>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Header

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path="user" element={<UserDashboard />} />
          </Route>

        </Routes>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Index

user dashboard:
export const UserDashboard = () => {

  return (
    <div className="user-container">
      <UserSidebar />
      <div className="xs main-container">Hello</div>
    </div>
  )
}

sidebar:
const openedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
  }),
  overflowX: "hidden"
})

const closedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
  }),
  overflowX: "hidden",
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`
  }
})

const DrawerHeader = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "flex-end",
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar
}))

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      "& .MuiDrawer-paper": openedMixin(theme)
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      "& .MuiDrawer-paper": closedMixin(theme)
    })
  })
)

const UserSidebar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

  return (
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
          <DrawerHeader>
            <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
              {theme.direction === "rtl" ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </DrawerHeader>

          <Divider />

          <List>
            <Link to="/dashboard/user">
              <ListItem disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
                <ListItemButton
                  sx={{
                    minHeight: 48,
                    justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                    px: 2.5
                  }}
                >
                  <ListItemIcon
                    sx={{
                      minWidth: 0,
                      mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                      justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                  >
                    <DashboardIcon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
                </ListItemButton>
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
         </List>
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
  )
}
export default UserSidebar
          


One way to solve this would be:

Move the [open, setOpen] state from the drawer to the header component and then pass the open state and setOpen function to the drawer as props. With that step, the header has now the information, whether the drawer is open or not.
If the state open is set to true, you can dynamically add a margin to your header container. The margin would be the width of the open drawer. I recommend using a global variable, so it is easier to keep track.

